# Number of real-time online users, node.js,jwt

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have an application,Users authenticate to login via JWT.When login is successful, I will mark this user "online:true",If the user log out, mark it as "online:false".However, if the user does not log out, I will not know in real time whether his token has expired.So the statistics are not reasonable.

I have considered these methods：

1. jwt expired event?
2. use setTimeout,setInterval
3. redis expired event?

The above methods are not good,

Comment: If I log into two browsers with the same userid and then log out of one, am I ”online” or out?

Comment: This is not a great use case for JWT - it’s meant to allow the server to NOT have to keep track of this. You might have to keep track of all issued tokens and their expirations and calculate as necessary (removing token references when expiration happens). At that point you are basically implementing sessions though.

Comment: Yes, I thought of a way. I used redis to save the user's refreshToken to redis. `RefreshToken:${userId}DeviceId:${deviceId}` This string as key, value is token and refreshTime.